# oracle database 12c enterprise m1 docker stuck at ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Tags: linux, oracle, docker

i want handle my database from server into local ,

docker : store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1

i have follow all guide for tns lost contact but stil no solve.

```
sh-4.2$ ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle
-rwxr-x--x 1 oracle oinstall 395722363 Mar  2  2017 /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/oracle
sh-4.2$ chmod u+s $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle
sh-4.2$
sh-4.2$ ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle
-rwsr-x--x 1 oracle oinstall 395722363 Mar  2  2017 /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/oracle
sh-4.2$ su

[oracle@e859f5f6994c /]$ ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle
-rwsr-x--x 1 oracle oinstall 395722363 Mar  2  2017 /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/oracle
```

then restart docker, right ? i am new on docker.

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba;
Enter password: Oradoc_db1
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

when the docker is started , this full my log.
[docker-store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yogithesymbian/9430f2cd7162146c8e3b5a51fc60b95b/raw/61ce24a3cd9443db81426f5fbdbce5142a1e0f3e/oracle.log)

edit 1

i have try with these one `epiclabs/docker-oracle-xe-11g` still on same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an Oracle 11g on Docker on my MacBook Pro M2.
This is due to the emulation of `amd64` and I found 2 workarounds.

This is what I have when try to connect inside the container using `sqlplus`:

```
[oracle@0a8a755deaef /]$ sqlplus system/xxx@ORCL

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Sep 19 14:09:12 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed
```

Note that the container is running in emulation mode (Apple Silicon chips is an `arm64` architecture while the image is an `amd64` image):

[image: Oracle container]

I'm running Docker 4.23.0.
**First workaround**: When I enable the experimental feature "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon (go to settings in Docker Desktop):

[image: enable Rosetta emulation]

Then just restarting a new container will allow `sqlplus` to connect correctly via SQL*Net:

```
[oracle@6987630c036b /]$ sqlplus system/xxx@ORCL

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Sep 19 15:20:53 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

**Second workaround**: Use native `arm64` Docker images to avoid going through emulation. However this is only possible starting from Oracle 19. Unfortunately Oracle does not propose `arm64` Docker images at the moment, so you will need to setup your base image by yourself (using a plain Linux `arm64` image and installing the Oracle rpm files, see https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle19c-linux-arm64-downloads.html).